# Checking to see if started_at is greater then 5 minutes

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm using laravel and I'm trying to grab all my items where the started_at is greater then 5 minutes and my completed_at is null. I should be getting some items but I'm just getting an empty array, so I'm hoping maybe someone can check my query out for me.

Here is my query

```
$items = Item::where('started_at', '>' Carbon::parse('started_at)->addMinutes(5))
                ->whereNull('completed_at)
                ->get()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
$items = Item::where('started_at', '<' now()->subMinitues(5))
    ->whereNull('completed_at)
    ->get();
```

`where('started_at', '<' now()->subMinitues(5))` mean that it has been more than 5 minutes since `started_at` - is my understanding correct - that's what you intend

Comment: If the answer solves the issue in your question pls remember to mark it as accepted/upvote for the benefit of subsequent visitors